# Mocking a type where interface signature's types are also mocked

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm trying to write a wrapper around an existing library that I do not want to edit, while allowing testing via mocking.

To allow for testing and mocking, I have created interfaces that satisfy the type signatures of the existing library and am using mockgen. I must also mock some of the types returned by the functions in these interface type signatures.

However, doing this causes the interface to no longer satisfy the existing library.

**Example:**

I have a `ClientType`, this has a function `Subscribe`, which returns a `SubscriptionType`.

```
func NewClientType() ClientType {
    return ClientType{"project name"}
}

type ClientType struct {
    projectID string
}

func (l *ClientType) Subscribe(subID string) SubscriptionType {
    return SubscriptionType{subID}
}

type SubscriptionType struct {
    subscriptionID string
}

func (t *SubscriptionType) Receive() {
    fmt.Println("Stuff")
}
```

I want to mock the `Receive` method.

This will allow me to create a Client, Subscribe it to a topic, and then mock this Receiving a message in testing.

I tried:

```
type MyLibraryWrapper struct {
    ClientType
}

type MockedClientType interface {
    Subscribe(string) MockedSubscriptionType
}

type MockedSubscriptionType interface {
    Receive()
}

func main() {
    client := NewClientType()

    myMockedType := NewWrapper(client)
    sub := myMockedType.Subscribe("a")
    _ = sub // use it
}

func NewWrapper(client ClientType) MyLibraryWrapper {
    return MyLibraryWrapper{client}
}
```

That gives:

```
cannot use client (type ClientType) as type MockedClientType in argument to NewWrapper:
    ClientType does not implement MockedClientType (wrong type for Subscribe method)
        have Subscribe(string) SubscriptionType
        want Subscribe(string) MockedSubscriptionType
```

Live demo:

https://go.dev/play/p/6Pr_Y4VtOAW

Answer (score 1):

Your library API is hardcoded to return `struct`s. You have to wrap each of its `struct` in an interface first before you can mock anything.

With embedding that task becomes easier.

```
type MyLibraryWrapper struct {
    ClientType
}

type MyClientType interface {
    Subscribe(string) MySubscriptionType
}

type MySubscriptionType interface {
    Receive()
}

func NewWrapper(client ClientType) MyClientType {
    return MyLibraryWrapper{client}
}
```

*Now* you can mock it...

```
type MockLibraryWrapper struct {}

type MockSubscriptionType struct {}

func (MyMockLibraryWrapper) Subscribe(string) MySubscriptionType {
    return MockSubscriptionType{}
}

func (MockSubscriptionType) Receive() {}

func NewMockClientType() MyClientType {
    return MockLibraryWrapper{}
}
```

Example usage:

```
func main() {
    realClient := NewWrapper(NewClientType())
    sub := realClient.Subscribe("a")
    sub.Receive()

    mockClient := NewMockClientType()
    sub := mockClient.Subscribe("a")
    sub.Receive()
}
```